# Understanding the proof of: $p$ is prime and $a \in \mathbb{Z}_p \implies x^p - a \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ is reducible.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-writing, field-theory, proof-explanation

I am trying to understand the proof of: $p$ is prime and $a \in \mathbb{Z}_p \implies x^p - a \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ is reducible. In the proof, it is shown that $a$ is a zero of $x^p - a$ which implies that $(x-a)$ is a factor of $x^p - a$. I follow the proof completely till this point. However, then the proof claims that $(x-a)$ being a factor of $x^p - a$ implies that $x^p - a$ is reducible over $\mathbb{Z}_p$. I don't understand how this is true; I can see why this would be true, intuitively, but I am trying to develop a formal proof for a more general statement. To be specific, inspired from this question, I am trying to prove:

If $F$ is a field s.t. $f(x) \in F[x]$ and $f(x)$ has a factor $(x-a) \implies$ $f(x)$ is reducible over $F$.

*Proof*. Suppose $F$ is a field s.t. $f(x) \in F[x]$ and that $f(x)$ has a factor $(x-a)$. Then, I thought of using the division algorithm, but the division algorithm is valid only for finite polynomials, not for any arbitrary polynomial in $F[x]$. So, I am having trouble completing this proof.

**My question**: Is what I am trying to prove even true? How can I complete the proof above?

**Edit**: The book that I am reading only has a definition of irreducible polynomials, which is as follows:

> A nonconstant polynomial $f(x) \in F[x]$ is *irreducible* over $F$ if $f(x)$ *cannot* be expressed as a product $g(x)h(x)$ of two polynomials $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ in $F[x]$ both of lower degree than the degree of $f(x)$.

Based on this, I think it would be valid to deduce the following definition:

A nonconstant polynomial $f(x) \in F[x]$ is *reducible* over $F$ if $f(x)$ *can* be expressed as a product $g(x)h(x)$ of two polynomials $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ in $F[x]$ both of lower degree than the degree of $f(x)$.

Comment: What is your definition of a polynomial being reducible?

Comment: @AryamanMaithani Please see the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Then, I thought of using the division algorithm, but the division algorithm is valid only for finite polynomials, not for any arbitrary polynomial in $F[x]$.

I'm not sure what you mean by "finite polynomials". In what way is $x-a$ not finite?

---

We shall assume $\deg f \ge 2$.

Since you have seen that $x - a$ is a factor, we must have that $f(x) = (x - a)g(x)$ for some $g(x) \in F[x]$. (By definition of "factor".)

Note that $\deg g = \deg f - 1$ and thus, both $g$ and $x-a$ have a degree strictly less than that of $f$ showing that $f$ is reducible.

---

Additional note: In $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$, we have the identity that $a^p = a$, so you can explicitly factor $x^p - a$ as $(x - a)^p$.

Comment: By a "finite polynomial", I mean that the polynomial can be expressed as a finite sum of terms (as opposed to an infinite formal sum). Are you getting $f(x) = (x-a)g(x)$ from the division algorithm?

Comment: Not exactly. In any ring $R$ with $a, b \in R$, we say that "$a$ is a factor of $b$" if (by definition) there exists $c \in R$ such that $ac = b$. That is all that I have used. In this case, $R = F[x]$, $a = x - a$ and $b = f(x)$. Of course, if I want to explicitly determine $g(x)$, I'd need the division algorithm.

Comment: In your proof, you say that "$(x-a)$ has a degree strictly less than that of $f$". This means that $f$ is a nonconstant polynomial. While this is rather immediate, is there a way (perhaps, a proof by contradiction) to show/argue that $f(x)$ is a nonconstant polynomial, given that it has a factor/zero?

Comment: $f$ could be constant. (Consider $f = 0$.) We need to have the assumption that $\deg f \ge 2$. (Something I originally did not write.)

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x)\in F[x]$,if $\deg f(x)>1$, and if $(x-a)\mid f(x)$, then $f(x)$ is reducible, since the assertion $(x-a)\mid f(x)$ means that there is some $p(x)\in F[x]$ such that$$f(x)=(x-a)p(x).\tag1$$Since $\deg f(x)>1$, $p(x)$ cannot be constant. So, $(1)$ tells us that $f(x)$ is reducible.